# mySQL query to check a string against a comma separated list value

Tags: mysql

i've been trying this one for a few hours. And searching previous questions for the right answer.

I have a table that contains a piece of content and has a number of keywords in a separate field (commaseplist) stored like this: **keyword1,keyword2,keyword3**

I'm trying to now display this content when one of the keywords from the list is found in the title of an article.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT * from conditional_content where LOWER(commaseplist) like '%article title goes here%' AND active=1
```

Obviously this isnt going to work. Other answers seem to mention FIND_IN_SET, but I guess i'm actually comparing two arrays, one being the title and the other being the comma separated list.

I could do this with PHP, but that just seems far to draining on the server.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are now learning why this is considered bad database design. The prudent thing would be to refactor your database and create separate tables for the keywords and for keyword-content relations.

Answer (score 0):

You could go here:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE title REGEXP CONCAT( "(", REPLACE( keywordstring, ",", "|" ), ")" )
```

This creates a simple regexp from your keyword string and matches that against your title.

This works for me (1st record gets selected, and the 2nd won't):

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `keywords` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `pdok_main`.`articles` (`title`, `keywords`) VALUES ('Expert opinion on cars', 'expert,cars');
INSERT INTO `pdok_main`.`articles` (`title`, `keywords`) VALUES ('Expert opinion on train', 'experts,trains');

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title REGEXP CONCAT( "(", REPLACE( keywords, ",", "|" ), ")" );
```

Comment: Thanks - this does make sense, but the "title" in this case would be "keyword1, keyword2, keyword3" and the keyword string would be the title of the article. Is it seems to be the wrong way around. the keywords are stored in this table (your_table) and the title is what i'm referencing against. Does that make sense?

Comment: You wrote: "... when one of the keywords from the list is found in the title ..."; have you tried this query?

Comment: Hi yes i've tried this. I did write that, but it's confusing. the keywords are associated with the conditional content, and the title is associated with the article. So I think in your suggestion the relationships are mixed. When I tired this is did not relieve the conditional content.

Comment: eg. **title** is "Expert Opinion on ...." and the conditional content is a bit of HTML displaying an expert icon. The keywords relating to the conditional content are **expert, professional, experienced**. So in this scenario the statment would need to pick up the word **Expert** from the title. Does this clarify my question? Sorry if it's not clear, and thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the answer; can you copy paste and check if this is like the situation you're stuck with?